# How to make buttons work on a messenger chatbot?

Tags: facebook-messenger

We are developing a Facebook Messenger chatbot but we are having issues integrating our chatbot with Facebook Messenger.

When, during a chat, the user sends a text message our webhook receives the data and does all the processing accordingly.

But when we send the user a menu with buttons and the user clicks the buttons instead of typing a message our webhook doesn’t receive the payload ar any other data that we were supposed to receive.

When the user starts a conversation with our chatbot we send them the following message:

```
{
   "recipient":{
      "id":"2492007720844646"
   },
   "message":{
      "attachment":{
         "type":"template",
         "payload":{
            "template_type":"button",
            "text”:”What do you prefer?”,
            "buttons":[
               {
                  "type":"postback",
                  "title”:”Blue",
                  "payload":"{'function':{'name':'color_blue'}}"
               },
               {
                  "type":"postback",
                  "title”:”Red”,
                  "payload":"color_red"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If the user clicks the button titled “Blue” our webhook doesn’t receive the payload “color blue”. On the other hand, if the user types the message “color blue” our webhook receives it without any problem.

If I try to simulate the problem using my own Facebook user, which is the app administrator, when I click the button the webhook receives the payload “color blue” without any problem but when any other user tries the same thing then our webhook won’t receive the payload. I suspect it is a problem with my app’s permission but I’ve already added to the app all permissions I think it needs.

[Click here to see an image with an example of what we are trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVabj.png)

Note that the options on the left are provided automatically by the bot and the user just need to click on those options to keep the conversation going. There is no need for the user to type anything. Our problem is that when the user clicks on the options in the left we don't receive that message and therefore we can't do anything.

I couldn’t find any documentation related to this kind of behavior, can someone help me, please?

Any help will be very welcomed.

Thanks and please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Most likely the issue is in your code. So it will help others to help you if you can provide a a minimal, complete and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: why would a bot need buttons?

Comment: Hi @YohanesGultom, thanks for getting back to me. I've added the piece of code I think is the culprit for this issue and added some more information to the post. I hope it can help. Once again thanks.

Comment: Hi @Stultuske, I need the buttons to control the flow of the conversation without having the user to type anything. A few options are given to the user and depending on what option chooses, by clicking in one of the buttons in a menu, different actions will happen. That's why we are using the buttons, to make the user to type less by offering them options through a menu with buttons where each button is an option that will trigger a different action.

Comment: By "our webhook won’t receive the payload", do you mean your server does not receive callback from fb server at all, or it receives a callback but with unexpected value/format? If you experience the former, you should check for API error log in Facebook Developer Console and post it here. Otherwise, post the unexpected response here.

Comment: Hi @YohanesGultom, our server does not receive callback at all. Regarding the Facebook Developer Console, I couldn't find it anywhere. Could you please point it out to me where I can find the console? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @Carlos you understand that a 'bot' is not a human user, and therefor doesn't need to 'click' buttons to indicate he wants something done, right?

Comment: @Carlos go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your app id}/messenger/settings/` Webhooks > show recent errors

Comment: @YohanesGultom, Thanks for pointing that out, we managed to find the console. When checking the Developer Console though it is empty, we don't get any error message there. Simply put nothing happens. We suspect it may be a permission problem. We have the permission "pages_messaging" but we don't have "pages_messaging_subscriptions", which we thought wasn't necessary. Should we request this extra permissions? Any extra thoughts on what could be our problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Carlos the dev console only shows recent errors (not sure how recent though). So try to monitor the console while triggering the error. If you don't receive any callback, an error should be shown over there. Even if it's a permission issue the error referring to it should pop up somewhere

Comment: Hi everyone, just trying to reactivate this thread as we couldn't find a solution for our problem. Unfortunately we can't find any error on our Facebook Developer Console to help us and we've tinkered with our app's permissions on Facebook but without success. It would be great if someone that have added buttons to their Facebook Messenger Chatbot could help us. I will try to add some images to exemplify what we are trying to do. Thanks!!!!